# What other ways to install ubuntu without using a flashdrive?

Tags: scripts

Curious about the other methods out there to install the operating system, Ubuntu.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, there are 5 Ways to install ubuntu:

1- Boot From a Live USB Drive or CD

2- Install Ubuntu On Windows With Wubi

3- Run Ubuntu In a Virtual Machine

4- Dual-Boot Ubuntu

5- Replace Windows With Ubuntu

(Read More [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/128347/5-ways-to-try-out-and-install-ubuntu-on-your-computer/))

Comment: Wouldn't recommend wubi at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows installed, You can directly boot (and install) from iso without burning it to DVD/CD/USB drive using **EasyBCD**.

Answer (score 1):

In detail,
   if you want to install the ubuntu without flash drive and all other  you have tried then you can also install it from **network**.

If your system is older and 
The network installer helps you install ubuntu in graphical form
See the link [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

Answer (score 1):

I have used Plop boot manager many times for installing different Linux Distros (including Ubuntu).  It allows me to boot a machine for a device that is not supported by the bios.  Very useful on machines that can not boot from USB.